# C# StringBuilder way to build string with sessions

Tags: c#, string, text, operators, stringbuilder

I have such piece of code how I'm building string:

```
foreach (var item in Session)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Session Parameter: [" + item.ToString() + "]<p />Guid Value: [" + Session[item.ToString()] + "]");
    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

I wonder, is such way correct? I mean, is `StringBuilder` here a very useful stuff?

And is this code faster without `StringBuilder`?

If it was built with the additional operators as `Label1.Text += ...`

As I remember `+=` uses more operations than `StringBuilder` as:

- making temp variable ( copy ) from the original string
- then changing the value of copy
- then redefining the original value with the value of copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not getting the benefits of `StringBuilder` because you are still concatenating your strings with `+`. A version optimized for `StringBuilder` would be:

```
foreach (var item in Session)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("Session Parameter: [");
    sb.Append(item.ToString());
    sb.Append("]<p />Guid Value: [");
    sb.Append(Session[item.ToString()]);
    sb.Append("]");

    Response.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Note: you can also move the `StringBuilder` initialization and call to `Response.Write` outside of the `foreach` as another possible improvement.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Any operator does make slowly string appending with the StringBuilder, doesn't it?

Comment: @OlegOrlov: Could you clarify what you mean by that? There’s only one string concatenation operator…

Comment: @minitech one? +, -, +=, -= ? maybe four for de/concatenation?

Comment: @OlegOrlov: `+` and `+=` are more or less the same thing. `-` and `-=` don’t work on strings… “deconcatenation” doesn’t exist.

Comment: @minitech same is not equal, but about the deconcatenation you are right... I thought that it was possible in C#, cause in some language I have seen such syntax...

Answer (score 3):

Why not create the `StringBuilder` once and use a single `Response.Write`?:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string item in Session)
{
    sb.Append("Session Parameter: [");
    sb.Append(item.ToString());
    sb.Append("]<p />Guid Value: [");
    sb.Append(((string)Session[item]));        
    sb.Append(']');
}
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

You should benchmark. I don't think there will be much difference unless the loop is very large.

Whenever you have concerns about performance, you should benchmark. The code that could get the greatest benefit from optimisation is not always where you would think it to be.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to restructure your code like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in Session)
{
    sb.Append("Session Parameter: [");
    sb.Append(item.ToString());
    sb.Append("]<p />Guid Value: [");
    sb.Append(Session[item.ToString()]);
    sb.Append("]");
}
Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

You only need one `StringBuilder` and one `Response.Write`.  Putting them in the loop defeats any optimization you might get from using the `StringBuilder` and there is no reason to do a `Response.Write` more than once.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your code as follows:

```
sb.Append("Session Parameter: [");
sb.Append(item); // ToString is implicit
sb.Append("]<p />Guid Value: [");
sb.Append(Session[item.ToString()]);
sb.Append("]");
```

Otherwise, the string builder is not that useful: all you do is appending a single value, which is constructed with an implicitly constructed builder created by the compiler for you.

The most important thing is moving the string builder and writing the response *outside* the loop.

Comment: Repeated concatenations are already optimized to `string.Concat`, which is pretty good IIRC. The loop is what matters (but `Response.Write` is also made for that, so… benchmark time!).

Comment: Shouldn't the next to last line be `sb.Append(Session[item].ToString());`, rather than `item.ToString()`?

Comment: @Tim This comes straight from the OP's code, so I assume that he wants to index by `item.ToString()`, rather than by `item`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight - Ah. I didn't catch that.  Never mind then :)

Answer (score 0):

Response.Write is more than enough for this task. String builder makes it slower.

```
foreach (var item in Session)
{
    Response.Write("Session Parameter: [");
    Response.Write(item.ToString());
    Response.Write("]<p />Guid Value: [");
    Response.Write(Session[item.ToString()]);        
    Response.Write(']');
}
```

Take a look at http://www.dotnetperls.com/response-write